# Collapse header on scrolling without using CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to implement the same behaviour than the CollapsingToolbarLayout for a view above my recyclerview that collapses to a minimum height on downscrolling and restores to its normal height when the scroll reaches the top. This header is not a Toolbar, hence the custom view.

I managed to do it, but when scrolling up it restores the height but the whole view starts flickering.

This is the header layout, I am trying to make the Textview disappear while keeping the inner linear layout visible at all times:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="welcome"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/always_show"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="12dp">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code

```
var maxHeight: Int = 0
var initialSize = false

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...

     header.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (initialSize)
                return
            initialSize = true
            maxHeight = header.measuredHeight
        }
    })

       recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (dy > 0) {
                //scroll down
                val params = header.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                params.topMargin = Math.max(params.topMargin-dy, -maxHeight/2)
                header.layoutParams = params
            } else if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                //top
                val params = header.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                params.topMargin = 0
                header.layoutParams = params                 
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Any ideas on how to make this animation more natural, closest to the CollapsingToolbarLayout behaviour.

Comment: Why don't you want to use CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: I'd start by looking into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.Behavior.html since that controls the built-in behavior.